# how to query delete just one row in sql server

Tags: sql-server

why i cannot to delete just one row in sql server .

this is my table and query, please corrected and give me solution.
thanks...

```
ID                  IdSuratKeluar               Type   KodePosition
FDBC015F-8DCB-44F2-956F-262A3FB379B6    CE7A98B8-7A98-45FC-A338-322BD8BE02BD    2   0041
656CBFFA-F279-461D-B1B8-61D07B348223    CE7A98B8-7A98-45FC-A338-322BD8BE02BD    2   0037
656CBFFA-F279-461D-B1B8-61D07B348225    CE7A98B8-7A98-45FC-A338-322BD8BE02BD    2   0037
```

My Query on SqlServer:

```
DELETE SuratKeluarPermission where KodeJabatan In 
( select Top(1) KodePosition from SuratKeluarPermission Where IdSuratKeluar='CE7A98B8-7A98-45FC-    A338-322BD8BE02BD' and KodePosition='0037')
```

Comment: `DELETE FROM`. You should read a bit about `SQL`.

Comment: And you don't have this column in your table: `KodeJabatan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
Select SuratKeluarPermission ,KodeJabatan,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY KodePosition ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) ) RN from SuratKeluarPermission 
)
DELETE FROM CTE where RN > 1
```

Comment: if I may ask for your help once again to the problems my queries on this link => "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26134978/how-to-create-query-join-with-multiple-conditions-in-sql-server". Thanks... =)

Answer (score 1):

This will delete a random row with the given criteria from your table:

```
;WITH CTE as
( 
  SELECT Top(1) *
  FROM SuratKeluarPermission 
  WHERE 
    IdSuratKeluar='CE7A98B8-7A98-45FC-A338-322BD8BE02BD' and 
    KodePosition='0037'
  ORDER BY NEWID()
)
DELETE FROM CTE
```

Disclaimer: I can't see in which world this would be useful